# why in the stackoverflow 2014 data dump, the files of meta.stackoverflow began on 2009-06

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, data-dump, meta-faq

I checked the meta.stackoverflow, the earliest post should be on Aug-05 2008. However, in the stackoverflow 2014 data dump, the files of meta.stackoverflow began on 2009-06. So where is the data in 2008? Thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am assuming you are talking about [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/can-i-answer-my-own-questions-even-if-i-knew-the-answer-before-asking), which was indeed asked on August 5th, 2008.

On [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2572/is-it-poor-etiquette-to-answer-your-own-question). (+10k link, as it has been deleted since on Stack Overflow)

And was **migrated** to Meta on the 25th of August 2009.

Simply put - Meta didn't exist in 2008. It has some posts that were created before it existed, because they were migrated in from an older site.

Comment: okay. I saw it. So actually, the meta.stackoverflow was created on 2009-06, right ?

Comment: Yes, Meta was launched in June 2009.